Instrumentation Amplifier and differential ADC Arduino Mega
I am working on an acquisition system, which measures tension and compression in a load cell. I amplify the signal with the Instrumentation Amplifier INA128P, and after that I connect it to the Arduino Mega differential ADC. Even though the signal is single-ended, I want to measure both tension and compression (positive and negative voltage), for this reason I connect it to the differential ADC port.
I am using the YZC-133 1kg load cell and I supply it with 5V, so the output is at most 5mV. The signal terminals are connected to the INA128P with a Gain of 1000 (maximum for this amplifier), using a Rg of 49 Ohms. Finally, I connect the signal output to the A0 port and the GND to A1.
Here are the electrical schematics for both the system and power supply. As you can see, the signal ground, microcontroller GND and power supply ground are the same, is it wrong?


The load cell and INA128P work well when I test it with an oscilloscope. The same for the ADC differential channels, I have tested it with a function generator, and I get to see the signal in the Arduino IDE scope. The problem is when I connected them the way I showed in the previous diagrams. The negative part of the output signal is being distorted.

a) Amplifier Output measured by oscilloscope b) Amplifier Output connected to microcontroller ADC and measured by oscilloscope
I have no idea how to solve it even following the recommendation in datasheet for this type of sensor. I have tried a couple of things both still do not work. I have read some instrumentation books and maybe the problem is the grounding. In the book it is recommended using the series earthing (for low frequencies, my case is 5 Hz), also a circuit shield and grounding on a certain point, but I am still unsure about that.
Furthermore, the output is a bit noisy, but I haven´t checked it since the other problem is worse. But after it is fixed, I would like to change it for an AC Coupled Instrumentation Amplifier Circuit. That would be adding a high pass filter to the output. What do you think? any further recommendations?
Thank you!

The Arduino's inputs are clamped to the supply rails with ESD protection diodes, so if you apply a potential outside the supply range, you will cause lots of current to flow, potentially damaging the device. Even though the Arduino's ADC may operate in differential mode, \$V_{A0}-V_{A1}\$, that does not mean that it can handle negative potentials at either input. With a supply \$V_{DD}=5V\$, you must ensure at all times that:
$$ 0V \le V_{A0} \le 5V $$
$$ 0V \le V_{A1} \le 5V $$
Your instrumentation amplifier has \$V_{REF}\$ (pin 5) at ground potential, 0V, causing its output to oscillate above and below 0V, in violation of this constraint. Fortunately, its output current is quite limited, and it is unlikely to have damaged the Arduino.
The Arduino's differential mode is only useful to remove common mode errors, such as would occur if for some reason its own ground potential differs from the amplifier's ground. If the ADC and amplifier are in very close proximity, and you've taken good care with grounding, there may be very little benefit to operating the ADC in differential mode. However, in keeping with your original idea, you can raise the amplifier's DC offset using its REF pin, and use that same REF potential as the input to the Arduino's A1:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Since the in-amp is powered from ±10V, and is able to produce output potentials well outside the ADC's acceptable input range, R1 is advisable to limit input current if ever clamping does occur. R2 is just to produce a potential offset similar to that caused by R1. This will have a very small influence on the accuracy of the ADC measurement, and if that's a problem, you'll have to protect the ADC in some other manner, such as changing the in-amp's power supplies such that it cannot produce an output outside the range 0V to \$V_{DD}\$.
The source of \$V_{REF}\$ must be low impedance. You may be able to employ a simple potential divider (below left), since everything is measured relative to \$V_{REF}\$, and variations in \$V_{REF}\$ will be removed by the differencing action of the ADC. Better solutions are shown middle (OK) and right (best):

simulate this circuit
They all produce \$V_{REF}=+2.5V\$, exactly half way between 0V and \$V_{DD}\$, which causes \$V_{A0}\$ to also be centered there. When the in-amp has zero potential difference at its inputs, it will produce +2.5V output. That output is able to rise and fall in either direction, positive or negative with respect to \$V_{REF}=+2.5V\$, while the ADC performs \$V_{A0}-V_{REF}\$.

Thank you, I was not conscious that I cannot handle negative potentials. I would like to ask for any recomendation for reducing noise. The output signal is a bit noisy and I have no idea if it comes from my mechanical design or the amplification.

@AngelFernándezPérez power supply, long wires, inadequate supply decoupling, poor grounding, inadequate shielding, all sources of noise.

Yes, it is wrong. Any inputs must be kept between the supply rails of the Arduino. Here is an approach for a DC-coupled amplifier. With 0V input to the INA128 the output will be approximately 2.5V so about 1/2 full scale of the ATmega ADC. The ADC will read from 0 to 5V so with a gain of 1000 the usable input voltage range will be nominally from -2.5mV (ADC 0x000) to +2.5mV (ADC 0x400)
Eg.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
OA1 can be an op-amp such as LM358, MCP601 etc. U1, OA1 and R1 create a reference voltage to offset the output of the in-amp using the REF input pin. It requires a buffer since the REF input pin is not high impedance.
R1 is chosen to draw 1mA so that U1 gets the minimum 1mA and R3 cannot cause the 5V line to rise, even if the IN128 is railed at +10V.
D2 and D3 clamp the in-amp output at just beyond the rails and R4 limits the input current resulting from any excursions beyond. -
